# how to keep data of localstack S3 after docker-compose down and later up

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, localstack

I am new with localstack I copied the docker-compose example. I made sure to mount the data path into my machine,and I do see it in host tmp folder,In addition I see my data being append when calling s3 write commands, but after I kill the docker-compose and start it from scratch I don't see the data from the previous session.
Is there a special flag that I need to add to reload the data?

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns,s3
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    ports:
       - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Example run:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://bucket-test
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 cp myfile.png  s3://bucket-test

#Now this command will return the file
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls s3://bucket-test
# But after I will kill the docker and run docker-compose up again I will see nothing
```

Answer (score 6):

Your data will be deleted by running `docker-compose down`. This stops **and removes** your containers: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

To stop the containers without deleting the volumes, run: `docker-compose stop`

I was able to keep data related to my ssm parameters by adding **"DATA_DIR"** and the following volumes :

```
 - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
 - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like :

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  localstack:
    build: ./localstack
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${LOCALSTACK_SERVICES:-ssm,cloudwatch,cloudformation}
      - DATA_DIR=${LOCALSTACK_DATA_DIR:-/tmp/localstack/data}
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./localstack/bootstrap:/opt/bootstrap/
      - ./data:/tmp/localstack
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
      - '443:443'
```

Comment: It says following `Persistence mode was activated using the DATA_DIR variable. DATA_DIR is deprecated and its value is ignored. The data is instead stored into /var/lib/localstack/state in the LocalStack volume.` I have mounted `/var/lib/localstack ` as volume but still no success.

Comment: https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/persistence-mechanism/

Comment: in the doc https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/
it is mentionned "Networks and volumes defined as external are never removed." So the mapped volumes remain

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the localstack documentation ([see "Deprecated" section](https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/configuration/)), `DATA_DIR` has since been deprecated. They ask that you use `PERSISTANCE=1` in the Description which will store the state in the `/var/lib/localstack/state` directory.

However, [`PERSISTENCE=1`](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/state-management/persistence/) is not equivilant to `DATA_DIR`. Following this deprecation, this is now a paid feature under Localstack Pro.

You now must use `S3_DIR` to specify your local S3 directory, it will only work if you specify your Localstack Pro API Key with `LOCALSTACK_API_KEY`.

Comment: `PERSISTENCE` not `PERSISTANCE`

Comment: i have a hard time spelling, just wonder how my team members feel when all our .env vars are spelled wrong, lol